# forloop.counter indicates how many times the for tag has gone through its loop

Tags: python, django, loops, counter

Currently going through the Django Tutorial (poll).

I understand that the for tag allows you to loop through a list or dict in order to do whatever you define.

But what is the purpose of counting the number of times the for tag goes through its loop?

Moreover, what is an example of a loop that goes over the same list/dict more than once?

Slightly confused here...

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1> 
{% if error_message %}
  <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
   <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
   <br />
 {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

What is the purpose of `foorloop.counter` in this case?

Comment: see my answer, i explained the purpose of this forloop.

Comment: I updated to explain how and why the `forloop.counter` is actually used in your second example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The template variable `forloop.counter` returns the current iteration of the current for loop, indexed from one. There are plenty of cases where one might use this variable. An example is this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Object</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for object in objects %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td> {# Print the number of the list, starting at 1 #}
                <td>{{ object }}</td> {# Print object unicode #}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Would print a table similar to this (of course with the appropriate rendering):

```
# | Object
------------
1 | Object 3
2 | Object 7
3 | Object 2
```

Note here that unless the QuerySet of objects is ordered in some way, their order may be arbitrary. The id of the object has no relation to the iteration of the for loop.

There is also `forloop.counter0` which will return the current iteration, indexed from 0.

---

Although your second question is somewhat unrelated, one might want to iterate over a list more than once to render information from that list in different sections. So maybe you have a list displaying information about an object, and then farther down the page a different list displaying different information about the object.

However, I would say that it is best to do what you can to avoid iterating over a list multiple times, as it is usually unnecessary.

Of course, don't worry about using this unless you need it, but it is good to know about I suppose.

---

In your updated example the `forloop.counter` variable is used to distinguish the choices in  the form. So `id` and `for` will both equal `choice#`, where `#` is the current iteration of the loop.

The `id` field of the `<input>` tag allows the `<label>` tag to identify (through the `for` field) for which `<input>` tag it should display. Otherwise, the label does not know which radio button to display with.

The documentation reads this about the purpose of the form:

> The above template displays a radio button for each question choice. The value of each radio button is the associated question choice’s ID. The name of each radio button is "choice". That means, when somebody selects one of the radio buttons and submits the form, it’ll send the POST data choice=# where # is the ID of the selected choice. This is the basic concept of HTML forms.

Note that the `forloop.counter` value is only used to correctly display the HTML form, and its value is not actually used in any significant way. The value of `forloop.counter` has no association with the actual choice, so you can see that the form POSTs the choice's `id`, rather than the `forloop.counter` value.

---

To give you a bit more clarification, here's an example where you *don't* need the `forloop.counter` variable.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Object</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for object in objects %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ object.pk }}</td> {# Print the pk of the object #}
                <td>{{ object }}</td> {# Print object unicode #}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Might print a table similar to this (of course with the appropriate rendering):

```
ID | Object
------------
3 | Object 3
7 | Object 7
2 | Object 2
```

In your view, you could order this list of objects according to their id/pk, as follows:

```
queryset = Object.objects.all().order_by('-pk') # Order all objects by pk in descending order
```

Then, that same template would render your table as follows:

```
ID | Object
------------
2 | Object 2
3 | Object 3
7 | Object 7
```

More often than not, every iteration of your for loop does the same thing, and you don't care which iteration it is. The example you posted from the tutorial is a great use of `forloop.counter`, but it's also not the only way of doing it. You could also use the choice's `pk` field, as we know this will be unique for each choice.

Comment: So 'forloop.counter' is pretty much a tool to display lists/dicts in order (ascending?), without hard coding them?

Comment: Nope, it's not-- That's what the `{% for %}` tag is. The `forloop.counter` variable (which is only available _inside_ a for loop) simply returns how many times you have gone through the loop so far. If you need this info, then great, use the variable. If you don't care, because every iteration does the same thing (which is most of the time), then don't worry about it.

Comment: Really confused. Why did they use `forloop.counter` in this case? Forms are pretty ubiquitous, no?

Comment: All they needed was something unique to each pair of `<input>` and `<label>` tags, so that the `<label>` tag would know which `<input>` tag it belonged to. The iteration of the for loop was unique to each pair, as was the id of the choice, which they could have alternatively used. I updated my question to clarify a bit more.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 1):

`forloop.counter` or `forloop.counter0` will help you if want to detect some specific step that you need. like:

```
{% for i in some_list %}
  {% if forloop.counter == 3 %}
    3rd element is special for me: {{i}}
  {% else %}
    {{i}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

the for loop that loops more than once over a list --- mm.. what should I say... the goal is actually to avoid things like this by rendering the needed object for 2nd loop from backend etc etc... you need to be more specific if you want more accurate answer for this.

```
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
  <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
  <br />
{% endfor %}
```

The purpose of this forloop is simple: to show all choices that the poll has.